# How to get longest line from a file together with its line number?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm interested to find out the line number of the longest line from a file.

For example, if I have a file with the following content:

```
lalala
tatatata
abracadabra
mu mu mu
```

how can I write a bash script that will give me an output something like this: `3 -> abracadabra`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a script for doing this. A simple command is enough:

```bsh
egrep -n "^.{$(wc -L < filename)}$" filename
```

This will work even when you have two or more lines with the same maximum length.

If you want that the output to be exactly in this form: `3 -> abracadabra`, then use:

```bsh
egrep -n "^.{$(wc -L < filename)}$" filename | sed 's/:/ -> /'
```

References:

- [Longest line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1655372/2353900)
- [Find the line number where a specific word appears with "grep"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10589929/2353900)

Comment: @don.joey: that's the power of unix. Simple commands, that can work together. here, he looks for "^.{n}$", ie any line that, between the beginning of line (`^`) and its end (`$`) has exactly n characters (`.{n}`).  Then he just needs to find n: for this he uses a GNU-ism, "wc -L filename" (note that this is not posix) which returns the length of the longest line of filename. So he greps any line that has the longest length. `$(cmd)` is replaced by the output of `cmd`.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Great comment.

Comment: Even better, you can also add (e.g.) `-C 3` to the grep options to get a few lines before and after for context

Comment: This doesn't work for very long lines, gets `grep: Regular expression too big`.  Of course, when I'm looking for long lines in a log so I can improve logging by making them shorter, it's the ones that are too big that I'm looking for

Answer (score 12):

You could use `awk` to print the length of each line (`length()`) and the line number (`NR`), then reverse (`-r`) `sort` the result by number (`-n`):

```
$ awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' tmp.txt
10 3 abracadabr
8 4 mu mu mu
7 2 tatatat
6 1 lalala
```

To show just the first line:

```
$ awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' tmp.txt | head -n 1
10 3 abracadabr
```

Comment: @user214965 please see my update, the line number displayed is the second number in the result.

Comment: What if there are 2 lines with the same maximum length?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu good point. +1 for `wc -L`, I didn't know about that argument. It is very useful indeed.

Answer (score 4):

A O(N) can be achieved with a perl one liner :

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { if (length > length $max) { $max=$_}}; print $max'
```

usages (where machin is a file name)

```
cat machin | perl -e 'while (<>) { if (length > length $max) { $max=$_}}; print $max'
```

or

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { if (length > length $max) { $max=$_}}; print $max' machin
```

or (less clear but shorter)

```
perl -ne 'if(length>length$m){$m=$_};END{print$m}' machin
```

Comment: Much, much more efficient. Thanks! Was looking for it.

Comment: Works with huge files +1

Answer (score 0):

O(n) 
For machines, for example OpenWRT, where perl is not available, @awk@ version might be useful.

```
awk 'length > l {l=length;line=$0} END {print line}' FILE
```

or python:

```
python -c "print max(open('$file', 'r'), key=len)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Radu's answer is perfectly sufficient and prefered, although if you want more explicit and shell-based solution, then you could use the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
longest_length=0
longest_string=0
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "${line}"]
do
    if [ "${#line}" -gt "${longest_length}" ]
    then
        longest_length="${#line}"
        longest_string="$line"
    fi
done < "$1"

echo "${longest_string}"
```

Usage: `./find_longest.sh input.txt`

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                          
1 2 
2 3 a a a a
4 5 6 
1 1 1 5

$ ./find_longest.sh input.txt                                            
2 3 a a a a
```